# How to send Reporting API reports cross-origin (Report-To) header

Tags: node.js, express, google-chrome, content-security-policy, preflight

I have an API which collects Content Security Policy (CSP) violation reports. Now that `report-uri` is being replaced by `report-to` directive, I planned to use that. However, I'm unable to get reports cross-origin. I've tried using the `cors` package. But still unable to get the report.

The headers I have set on client origin (example-1.com) are:

```
res.setHeader(
    'Report-To',
    '{"group":"csp-endpoint","max_age":10886400,"endpoints":[{"url": "https://example-2.com/csp-report"}]}'
);
```

In CSP, the `report-to` value is set to `csp-endpoint` (This is working on same origin)

On server-side (example-2.com), the following code is present (Express.js server):

```
app.use(
    '/csp-report',
    express.json({
        type: [
            'application/json',
            'application/csp-report',
            'application/reports+json'
        ]
    })
);

app.use('/csp-report', cors()) // Using cors npm package

app.post('/csp-report', (req, res) => {
    res.setHeader('Access-Control-Expose-Headers', '*, Authorization');
    console.log(req.headers);
    console.log('CSP Violation Timestamp : ' + new Date().getTime());
    console.log(req.body);
    res.status(204).send();
});
```

I'm not getting reports from cross origin. Please consider me a beginner and let me know where I'm making mistake. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code appears to be correct, but there is currently a bug in Chrome/Chromium's implementation of CORS for the Reporting API, which is likely to be causing your problem. See [Chromium issue #1152867](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=1152867). The gist of the bug is that the CORS implementation used here requires that an `Access-Control-Allow-Methods: POST` header exists on the response, which is not compliant with the CORS spec, as `POST` is a "simple" method.

If you are able to modify the CORS implementation on your server, you can modify it to always include the `Access-Control-Allow-Methods: POST` header on the `OPTIONS` response, which should work around the bug.

Otherwise, you will have to either not use a cross-domain request for reporting, or fall back to only using the deprecated `Report-Uri` directive until the fix is released. The latter shouldn't be too much of an issue, as Firefox and Safari don't support the new `Report-To` header yet anyway.

Comment: This is what I was looking for. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

CSP reporting API is not a subject of CORS, because no resources are loaded from the server. Browser just send a report and does not expect any headers/response from CSP reporting API. To show this you return the `204 No content` header so that the browser does not expect a response.

*Why do you think that you have a CORS issue?* When you proxying site via Cloudflare.com, it injects into all pages a `NEL/Report-to` (the same as `CSP/Report-to`) headers with CF's own domain without any CORS issue:
[image]
I had implemented a lot of endpoints for `report-uri` and never face any CORS issues.

Note that `report-uri` is obsolete in favour `report-to` directive, but browsers does not supports `report-to` except Chrome.

> 

When you simulate sending a report for testing purposes, do not use an ordinary ajax POST request - it is subject to CORS.
To imitate sending real report, generate a page on third-party domain:

```
<script>alert('inline success')</script>
```

and send it with CSP header:

```
Content-Security-Policy: "default-src 'report-sample' report-uri https://your_reporting_api.com/endpoint;"
```

When debug it's easier to use `report-uri` not `report-to`.

Comment: I'm returning 204 header but it still doesn't seem to work on other origins. It only succeeds sending the report on same origin.

Comment: I have updated the answer with some relevant info. My question still in force: *Why do you think that you have a CORS issue?*

Comment: Note that you can also use Fiddler to watch for error reports, or configure a NetLog capture: https://textslashplain.com/2020/01/17/capture-network-logs-from-edge-and-chrome/ and look at the REPORTING tab in the Viewer https://netlog-viewer.appspot.com/#import

Comment: @granty Check this link out: https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2018/09/reportingapi . This clearly states that `Note: If your endpoint URL lives on a different origin than your site, the endpoint should support CORs preflight requests. (e.g. Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *; Access-Control-Allow-Methods: GET,PUT,POST,DELETE,OPTIONS; Access-Control-Allow-Headers: Content-Type, Authorization, Content-Length, X-Requested-With`

Comment: @EricLaw I tried NetLog capture. However, it only shows that request failed. It doesn't show what error occurred.

Answer (score 0):

When configured with a `report-to` directive, CSP reports will use the [Reporting API](https://w3c.github.io/reporting/) to send the reports. The browser will require CORS for cross-origin reports in that case, and it's possible that your server is not correctly configured to negotiate CORS on that URL. (I don't know the details of the npm package you're using, but that would be my suspicion).

The browser will send a pre-flight request of the form:

```
OPTIONS /csp-report HTTP/1.1
Access-Control-Request-Headers: content-type
Access-Control-Request-Method: POST
Origin: example-1.com
```

And your server needs to respond with something like:

```
200 OK HTTP/1.1
Access-Control-Allow-Headers: content-type
Access-Control-Allow-Methods: POST
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: example.com
Access-Control-Max-Age: 3600
```

If that happens, then the second request (with the actual report) will be sent.

The Chrome [NetLog viewer](https://support.google.com/chrome/a/answer/6271171) can be useful for debugging these sorts of problems.

As well, recent versions of Chrome have experimental support in DevTools for Reporting. You should be able to see configured endpoints, as well as reports which have been queued. (Chrome 96 instructions: Open devtools, click the gear icon for settings, and under "experiments" there is an option labeled "Enable Reporting API panel in the Application panel")

Comment: I allowed those headers. It's still not working. Also, NetLog viewer is just showing that it failed. It doesn't show the reason it seems.